# Having problems with MIDI in recording on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, keyboard, music, midi, lmms

I have a Yamaha P-120 model with a USB to MIDI interface that looks like this.

[image: USB to MIDI interface]

I've decided to use [LMMS](https://lmms.io/) because it seems like the easiest MIDI sequencer available. I'm having a lot of difficulties getting this to work.

- **What I am trying to do**: Record input from my keyboard onto LMMS
- **What is working**: I can get my output to work, so I can control my keyboard via my computer.
- **What is not working**: My computer isn't reading the input from the keyboard. I can't record any songs.
- **What have I tried**: A lot.

**Ports/Any other Information**

```
Port     Client name                       Port name
14:0     Midi Through                      Midi Through Port-0
24:0     USB Midi                          USB Midi MIDI 1
128:1     LMMS                              Default preset
128:2     LMMS                              Default preset
128:4     LMMS                              Default preset
129:0     Client-129                        qjackctl
```

Let me know if you need anything else to help. I am really trying hard to fix this problem as I would love to use my MIDI keyboard.

Comment: Does `aseqdump -p "USB Midi"` work?

Comment: yes. my output reads:
     `24:0   Clock
     24:0   Clock
     24:0   Clock
     24:0   Clock
 24:0   Active Sensing
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Stop
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Active Sensing
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Clock
 24:0   Stop`

Comment: Found out some things more with my interface: `aconnect -i
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
    0 'Timer           '
    1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 28: 'USB Midi' [type=kernel]
    0 'USB Midi MIDI 1 '
    ' ` and `aconnect -o
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 28: 'USB Midi' [type=kernel]
    0 'USB Midi MIDI 1 '
client 128: 'FLUID Synth (3237)' [type=user]
    0 'Synth input port (3237:0)' `

Comment: Also, I am following this tutorial now and so far I am still having problems with the MIDI http://tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MIDI command bytes for Clock, Stop, and Active Sensing are F8, FC, and FE.
In binary, this would be `11111000`, `11111100`, and `11111110`.

The MIDI protocol has no synchronization or error correction; this looks like noise on the MIDI data line, i.e., there is no actual MIDI signal.

Reasons for this could be:

- the MIDI input cable is broken;
- the keyboard's MIDI output is broken; or
- the "HOST SELECT" switch is not set to "MIDI".

Comment: It is possible the MIDI cable is broken, except that I was getting output to the keyboard through my computer (So I think that it would mean that MIDI IN would have to be the only cord broken). Host select switch is set to MIDI. I hope its not a hardware failure. The only way I can think of making sure it isn't a hardware failure is to make sure there isn't some weird driver/problem with Yamaha keyboards and MIDI connections. (I've found stuff online saying Yamaha is special).

Comment: I might just purchase another cable and see if that works. I'll be able to tell you if it was hardware failure after I see how a new cable reacts to the connection (unless the hardware failure is on the keyboard itself like you suggested).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an Yamaha PSR-2000, the same MIDI to USB cable and Debian 12, and found this page. Here I learn about the `aseqdump` command. With it I could troubleshoot and find a solution to me: Just turn on both MAIN and LAYER on the right side of the LCD screen. Once I did that all the notes were sent to the host.

Comment: As this is a Ubuntu only site do you know for sure this works with Ubuntu?

Comment: As far as troubleshoot isn't a distro specific problem, the culprit was the interaction between the instrument and the generic cable. Also have in mind I can't even be sure if this works with other models of keyboards or cables. I decided to share here because even not using Ubuntu, I'm using Debian and both share a lot of the same software, and the chances are more im favor of working than not. I wish you hood luck